# Joining Onto Partition Statement HANA SQL

Tags: sql, hana

I am trying to join two tables to the following query:

```
SELECT "NUMBER",
"U_ANALYZED_DATE",
"DV_SALES_ACCOUNT",
"U_USD_TOTAL_POTENTIAL_NNACV" 
FROM 
    (select *, row_number() over ( partition by "DV_SALES_ACCOUNT" order by "U_ANALYZED_DATE" desc ) rownum 
      from "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST")
WHERE rownum = 1
AND "DV_SALES_CATEGORY" = 'Compliance'
AND "DV_STATE" NOT IN ('Closed Canceled')
AND (YEAR("U_ANALYZED_DATE") = '2019' AND MONTH("U_ANALYZED_DATE") IN ('10','11','12')
OR YEAR("U_ANALYZED_DATE") = '2020' AND MONTH("U_ANALYZED_DATE") IN ('1','2','3'))
AND "U_USD_TOTAL_POTENTIAL_NNACV" > 0
ORDER BY "U_ANALYZED_DATE" desc
```

The tables should be joined as follows:

```
JOIN "SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT" on "SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT"."NAME" = "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT"
JOIN "SURF_RT"."SALES_CONTRACT" on "SURF_RT"."SALES_CONTRACT"."DV_ACCOUNT" = "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT"
```

I am getting an error no matter what I try and it has to be because of the partition. Does anyone know the solution here?

Comment: Why error are you getting? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60517489/edit) to provide this important piece of information.

Comment: Seems I get the same error with this and the solution:

Comment: Could not execute 'SELECT "NUMBER", "U_ANALYZED_DATE", "DV_SALES_ACCOUNT", "U_USD_TOTAL_POTENTIAL_NNACV" FROM ( select ...'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [260]: invalid column name: SURF_RT.SALES_REQUEST.DV_SALES_ACCOUNT: line 13 col 43 (at pos 375)

Comment: Could not execute 'SELECT "NUMBER", "U_ANALYZED_DATE", "DV_SALES_ACCOUNT", "U_USD_TOTAL_POTENTIAL_NNACV" FROM (select ...'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [260]: invalid column name: SURF_RT.SALES_REQUEST.DV_SALES_ACCOUNT: line 8 col 70 (at pos 306)

Comment: but it works without the joins

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* that you just need to alias the derived table so you can then refer to join it. In many databases this is mandatory anyway, but apparently not in Hana (otherwise your original query would not run).

But to join on a derived table (the resultset that is generated by the subquery), alias do help:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM 
    (
        select 
            *, 
            row_number() over ( partition by "DV_SALES_ACCOUNT" order by "U_ANALYZED_DATE" desc ) rownum 
        from "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"
    ) sr  -- table alias
JOIN "SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT" 
    ON "SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT"."NAME" = "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT"
JOIN "SURF_RT"."SALES_CONTRACT" 
    ON "SURF_RT"."SALES_CONTRACT"."DV_ACCOUNT" = sr."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT" --reference to the derived table
WHERE 
    ...
```

Side notes:

- you should use table aliases for other tables involved in the query too, in order to make the code more readable
- you should also prefix each column in the query with the identifier of the table it belongs to, so the query is unambiguous (and easier to maintain)

Comment: I still get the error above. This is a real strange one for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this query is not "that the `where rownum = 1` needs to be at the end" but that the OP got confused by the bracketing of SQL expression.
More specifically, trying to reference the sub-query data by specifying join conditions against the base table that is used in the sub-query:

```
JOIN "SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT" 
  on "SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT"."NAME" = "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT"
JOIN "SURF_RT"."SALES_CONTRACT" 
   on "SURF_RT"."SALES_CONTRACT"."DV_ACCOUNT" = "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT"
```

Since the sub-query (derived table) is used in the query and should be used for the join, **it** needs to be referred in the join condition, instead.
So, yes, it needs a table alias here and the join conditions need to refer to it.

```
SELECT 
      ...
FROM 
    (select *
          , row_number() over 
            (partition by "DV_SALES_ACCOUNT" 
             order by "U_ANALYZED_DATE" desc) rownum 
     from 
          "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST") sr
   INNER JOIN "SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT" sa
         on sa."NAME" = sr."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT"
   INNER JOIN "SURF_RT"."SALES_CONTRACT" sc
        on sc."DV_ACCOUNT" = sr."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT"
 WHERE 
     sr.rownum = 1
AND "DV_SALES_CATEGORY" = 'Compliance'
AND "DV_STATE" NOT IN ('Closed Canceled')
AND     (YEAR("U_ANALYZED_DATE") = '2019' 
         AND MONTH("U_ANALYZED_DATE") IN ('10','11','12')
     OR YEAR("U_ANALYZED_DATE") = '2020' 
         AND MONTH("U_ANALYZED_DATE") IN ('1','2','3'))
AND "U_USD_TOTAL_POTENTIAL_NNACV" > 0
ORDER BY 
        "U_ANALYZED_DATE" desc;
```

With just this little bit of standard SQL syntax and formatting of code the query got a lot easier to understand.

Now it's even obvious that the IN conditions for `MONTH` and `YEAR` should in fact be integers, not strings as these functions return integers.

```
SELECT 
      ...
FROM 
   (SELECT *
         , row_number() over 
           (partition by "DV_SALES_ACCOUNT" 
            order by "U_ANALYZED_DATE" desc) rownum 
    FROM 
         "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST") sr
   INNER JOIN "SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT" sa
         on sa."NAME" = sr."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT"
   INNER JOIN "SURF_RT"."SALES_CONTRACT" sc
        on sc."DV_ACCOUNT" = sr."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT"
 WHERE 
     sr.rownum = 1
     AND "DV_SALES_CATEGORY" = 'Compliance'
     AND "DV_STATE" NOT IN ('Closed Canceled')
     AND (   YEAR("U_ANALYZED_DATE") = 2019 
             AND MONTH("U_ANALYZED_DATE") IN (10, 11, 12)
          OR YEAR("U_ANALYZED_DATE") = '2020' 
             AND MONTH("U_ANALYZED_DATE") IN (1 , 2 , 3 )
          )
     AND "U_USD_TOTAL_POTENTIAL_NNACV" > 0
ORDER BY 
        "U_ANALYZED_DATE" DESC
```